# Magento 2 - How to configure REST API?

Tags: rest-api, magento2.3.2, webapi

I want to create REST API in Magento 2.3.2 for Mobile Application but I have few confusions regarding REST API. Can anyone guide me on this, please?

- Is there any quick start or say ready-made API structure available. Like this one https://github.com/DivanteLtd/magento2-review-api
- Is it necessary to build API for all Module? (Like Catalog, Customer, Order etc). I am asking this because I have read that Magento 2 by default provide REST API, So can I reuse it?
- How can I Implement Token-based authentication? I want to access My Magento 2.3.2 Site data using CURL. how can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Magento2 used **swagger** for API. All APIs is already build https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger